# the significance of an adjective in front of an preposition "of "

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases, adjective-phrases

In general, an noun or an pronoun is located in front of an preposition "of".
By the way, I happen upon some sentences including an adjective.

> The gallery is full of people.

> The society is free of poverty and disease.

In both sentences, both full and free are the adjective

I conceive there is definitely a grammatical reason why these adjective stand between a verb "be" and a preposition "of".

Please, let me know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

*Full* and *free* are predicate adjectives. The following preposition phrases qualify the meaning of the adjectives.

Something can be full of people, full of money, full of problems. It may be that the context makes it clear, and the preposition phrase can be omitted:
*The piggy bank is full [of coins]*.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositional phrases can modify a variety of things, including

- Verbs: It **smells** of honey
- Adjectives: There is no reason to be **afraid** of bears
- Nouns: Many people have a **fear** of bears

Certain verbs, adjectives, and nouns "expect" certain prepositions, and it does not always follow a simple pattern. For example, you could say the gallery is "full **of** people" or "filled **with** people", but "filled **of** people" is incorrect.